# How to insert(merge) data to existing datatable using datareader

Tags: datagridview, insert, merge, datareader

what i was trying to do is to generate a list of products added by user into the datagridview but as i am using datatable.load(datareader) it always reset the previous value of the datatable,i also tried datatable.load(datareader,upinsert) but same thing is happening again.

```vb
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Then
            cn = connectdb("MSMS.mdb", "")
            Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Code,Product,Pack,Batch,Expiration,Free,MRP,Rate,CST,VAT,CD,SD FROM product WHERE Product ='" + DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString + "'", cn)
            Dim dr2 As OleDbDataReader
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(dr2, LoadOption.Upsert)
            DataGridView3.DataSource = dt
```

i want to insert into datatable every time when Enter is pressed along with the last result?

Comment: the best thing to do is use order by on select statement. So if you have created date you can do desc so that the latest record will be showed first on the first row.

Comment: @BizApps no you didn't understand the problem,i know how to use desc in query,the problem is when you press enter the old result of datagridview3 reset to the new,i want to make it a list by adding one after another.

Comment: @BizApps and how that's gonna help here,read the question once again it has to be datatable,datagridview,datareader